# What significance and applications does nanotechnology have in chemistry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, nanotechnology

Specifically concerning **organic chemistry**, but an explanation on its significance and applications in inorganic chemistry would be great as well.

Comment: The question title as written seems too broad. There are lots of examples of applications of nanotechnology throughout chemistry. There are so many that it would be hard to imagine that there is **one definitive answer** to this question. Now, for the more localized question of organic chemistry, I think we have a better chance. Perhaps if this question was specific to organic and you asked another question about inorganic chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

There is branch named [Chemical Nanoscience and Nanotechnology](http://www.rsc.org/Membership/Networking/InterestGroups/ChemicalNanoscience/) Which deals with chemistry asspects.

Talking about organic chemistry, nanotechnology is used for Organic synthesis.

With help of Modern Chemistry today we can synthesis almost all complex molecules, thanks to nanotechnology.

Check out [Wikipedia-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotechnology#Bottom-up_approaches), 
[Wikipedia-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotechnology#Simple_to_complex:_a_molecular_perspective) and [nano.gov](http://www.nano.gov/you/nanotechnology-benefits)

---

For organic chemistry, [Polymer nanotechnology](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0032386108003157) is developed notably.  Polymer matrix and nanocomposites have become a prominent area of current research and development

Example:

[exfoliation](http://eng.thesaurus.rusnano.com/wiki/article1987)

[image: exfoliation]

Comment: This answer has been flagged as VLQ. While I do not agree with this flag, I and the OP probably too would appreciate and example for the use of nanotechnology in organic synthesis.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I have edited the answer and added example